# Drupal7 Displayed Username different from Username Entry Field

Tags: drupal-7

On our Drupal 7 site, we're trying to force Drupal to use a certain username- First Name, Last Initial - no matter what the user puts in the username field on the user form. Currently, there are fields for Username, First Name, and Last Name. Does anyone have an easy way to do this? It would also be nice if the user profile's URL would take be forced to use the Drupal-created username.

I've looked around and haven't seen any questions on this- let me know if I missed one!

Answer (score 0):

There is a module that do just that [RealName](http://drupal.org/project/realname) and it fairly easy to use and this is the [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/realname) for the module if needed.

and you can alter the user profile link with [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) to what ever you want.